# npm run zip and yarn zip is failed ... it is responding errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

it is returning errors
I'm using nvm ... and tried the following node version:
v12.0.0
v13.0.0
v13.14.0
v14.0.0

```
    Built the bundle with browser support for >1%, last 4 versions, Firefox ESR, not ie  'D:\apachehtdocs\divi\wp-content\plugins\divi3\Gruntfile.js'
    at Object.symlinkSync (fs.js:962:3)
    at Object. (D:\apachehtdocs\divi\wp-content\plugins\divi3\node_modules\divi-scripts\scripts\zip.js:34:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:826:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! divi3@0.1.0 zip: 
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the divi3@0.1.0 zip script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```